# Get event color from Google Calendar to Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, google-calendar

I have synced up Google Calendar events to my Outlook (Outlook 365 ,16.0.13929.20222).

One feature I extensively use in GCal is to give meetings different color based on topic.
Is there a way to sync these colors between Outlook and GCal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Outlook Google Calendar Sync](https://github.com/phw198/OutlookGoogleCalendarSync) that not only syncs the colors but all kind of calendar events in both ways. I highly recommend using it.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there seems to be no option in Outlook that could meet it directly. But I found some related articles about third-party tools, please check if it could be helpful to you.

https://www.companionlink.com/support/kb/How_to_sync_Outlook_Category_Colors_to_Google_Calendar_Modern_Colors

https://www.companionlink.com/support/kb/How_to_Sync_Outlook_Color_Categories_with_Google_Calendar